# Windows phone 8.1 StatusBar ProgressIndicator doesn't 'animate'

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, statusbar

First I set 
`Windows.UI.ViewManagement.StatusBar.GetForCurrentView().ProgressIndicator.ProgressValue = 0;`
to hide the progress bar, but now I want to make it appear again, with the loading animation, how to do that?

Comment: Set it to Visible and Indeterminate so it spins. Voila...

Comment: http://www.visuallylocated.com/post/2014/04/06/Showing-the-system-ProgressIndicator-in-a-Windows-Phone-81-XAML-app.aspx

Comment: Do you want a determinate or indeterminate progress bar? The latter has the 'dancing dots' that animate left to right.

Comment: `Windows.UI.ViewManagement.StatusBar.GetForCurrentView().ProgressIndicator.ProgressValue = null;`
this is what I needed, thank you all